# Realizing two $n$-types simultaneously

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\Sigma(u_1 \dots u_n), \Sigma'(u_1 \dots u_n)$ be complete $n$-types of an $\mathcal{L}$-theory $T$, where $\mathcal{L}$ is a countable language.

> Q1: Is there a model $\mathcal{M} \models T$ such that $\mathcal{M}$ realizes both $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$?

> Q2: If so, can we choose $\mathcal{M}$ to be countable?

I know a few theorems which seem like they might be relevant:

1. A principal complete $n$-type of $T$ must be realized by any model of $T$.
2. If $\Sigma$ is a complete $n$-type of $T$ and $\mathcal{M} \models T$, then there exists an elementary extension of $\mathcal{M}$ which realizes $\Sigma$.
3. If $\Sigma$ is a non-principal complete $n$-type of $T$ then there exists a countable $\mathcal{M} \models T$ such that $\Sigma$ is not realized in $\mathcal{M}$.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen Yes, I forgot about that assumption. Thank you for catching that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assume $T$ is complete.

Let $M$ be an arbitrary model of $T$. Realize $\Sigma$ in an elementary extension $M\preceq M'$. Then realize $\Sigma'$ in an elementary extension $M'\preceq M''$. Done and done.

If you want the model to be countable, use Löwenheim-Skolem to find a countable elementary submodel of $M''$ containing the realizations of $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$.

If $T$ is not complete, then $\Sigma$ and $\Sigma'$ might disagree about $L$-sentences, in which case they obviously can't be simultaneously realized.

Comment: Thank you for this. Where did we use the assumption that $T$ is complete? (Perhaps there's a mistake in the statement of Thrm 2?)

Comment: @Pascal'sWager Perhaps... why don't you think about their last remark and see if you can come up with a counterexample.